# Laravel: Removing Html, CSS and ect. in Summernote Editor like Notepad

Tags: javascript, laravel, summernote

I am updating a website. This website is made in Laravel 5.7
Here is used of Summernote Editor for the textarea.

The problem that I have is:
I want to make sure that as soon as a user pastes a piece of text in the Summernote editor (textarea), that piece of text becomes a 100% plain text; that all Html and Css and ... get removed like in Notepad.

I spent a day trying to get the problem solved with javascript and jquery but it didn't work.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#input_description').summernote({
                callbacks: {
                    // Clear all formatting of the pasted text
                    onPaste: function (e) {
                        var bufferText = ((e.originalEvent || e).clipboardData || window.clipboardData).getData('Text');
                        e.preventDefault();
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            document.execCommand('insertText', false, bufferText);
                        }, 10);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

I hope you can help me with it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "removed" in what way? `I spent a day trying to get the problem solved` what did you try?

Comment: thx, I have just edited my text